# how can we merge two columns with different names belonging to two different table into a single column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Consider table 1 as `vendor_details` and table 2 as `customer_details`.

Table 1: vendor_details

```
vendor_Id     vendor_Name
-------------------------------

 v001         ABC Enterprises
 v002         XYZ  Traders
```

Table 2 :customer_details

```
customer_Id      customer_Name
----------------------------------

c001             ItUs Software
c002             RTech Solutions
```

Expected Output :

```
trader_id      trader_name
-----------------------------
v001           ABC Enterprises
v002           XYZ  Traders
c001           ItUs Software
c002           XYZ  Traders
```

Answer (score 2):

The `union all` set operator is exactly what you need:

```
SELECT vendor_id AS trader_id, vendor_name AS trader_name
FROM   vendor_details
UNION ALL
SELECT customer_Id AS trader_id, customer_Name AS trader_name
FROM   customer_details
```

Note: The column aliases on the second query are redundant, but I added them to make the query easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
select vendor_id as trader_id, vendor_name as trader_name 
from vendor_details
union all
select customer_id, customer_name
from customer_details
```

Answer (score 1):

Using union all like this

```
select * from 
(select vendor_id as trader_id
,vendor_name as trader_name
from vendor_details
union all
select customer_id as trader_id
,customer_name as trader_name
from customer_details)a
```